# Can't create table (errno:121) when importing mysql workbench export dump only on Linux

Tags: mysql, linux, hibernate, mysql-workbench

I created a .sql dump file by exporting my tables using MySQL Workbench on a Windows machine. If I try to import that file again on Windows, everything works fine. If I try to import that file using `mysql -u user -p TABLE < dumpfile.sql`, I get a `Can't create table (errno:121)` error.

The original tables were created by Hibernate. A table which causes the problem is this many-to-many relationship:

```
CREATE TABLE USER_ITEM (
  USERID int(11) NOT NULL,
  ITEMID int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (USERID,ITEMID),
  KEY FK_7ykraq12rrlicwxhjfs13re56 (ITEMID),
  CONSTRAINT FK_7ykraq12rrlicwxhjfs13re56 FOREIGN KEY (ITEMID) REFERENCES item (ID),
  CONSTRAINT FK_c8pcrsn7fey94ipgiy12g3d4e FOREIGN KEY (USERID) REFERENCES user (ID)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

It seems like Hibernate and Workbench created an index on ITEMID which has the same foreign key as my first constraint. Why? And why causes this only a problem when importing my dump file on Linux but not on Windows using MySQL workbench? Can I just rename the first constraint's foreign key?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that there was a problem with my database. Recreating it solved that problem.